# T-SQL Function: Invalid object name

Tags: sql-server

I have read several posts with similar topic headers but I don't think my question is answered.

I created a function (say `dbo.fnABC()`) with:
`Returns Table` . . . and 
`Select Top 10` 
. . . and executed it.

Then I created a Query:

```
Select * from dbo.fnABC()
```

. . . and it returns the expected 10 rows.

However, in both the Function AND the Query, `dbo.fnABC()` has a red, squiggly underline and a quick hover shows:

> Invalid object name dbo.fnABC()

It's working and all - but I would like to know why the squiggly lines under the Function name?
What will make it a valid object name?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intellisense is cached and you should refresh that cache. Disabling and re-enabling Intellisense should do that (using the button on the toolbar right next to 'New Query') or use the shortcut keys `ctrl+shift+r` to refresh the cache directly. The red suiggly should now disappear.

Answer (score 2):

In SSMS, try "Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache".

And then wait for a few seconds to see if it's now recognized.

Comment: Sorry. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.